# How to share tests/steps in Robot Framework?

Tags: automated-tests, pycharm, robotframework

Sorry for the trivial question, but how to share steps in Robot Framework (pyCharm)? I have a test case that covers loging into account (login.robot) and another test case that conducts an action after logging in. How do I use the steps from first case so I don't have to write them again? Should I put them in 'Resource' file? Or set as resource that case 'login.robot'? Or maybe put it in 'Keywords'?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Have you actually _tried_ putting them in resource files to see how they work? Resource files are well documented in the user guide.

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to leverage keywords which is fundamental of robot framework.  As @Bryan has indicated, please play around with this and do your own research as you'll learn so much more from it.

Comment: See the demo from the Robot Framework team: https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/webdemo

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a keyword to perform login and use it in both of your test cases. In second test case the keyword could be part of setup. Below is just a rough exmaple

```
    *** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Resource          C:\\development\\robot-scripts\\sshlibrary\\login.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Open the Login Page of Yahoo Mail
    Open Login Page
    Close Browser
```

Resource File

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     An example resource file
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${HOST}           mail.yahoo.com
${LOGIN URL}      https://${HOST}/
${BROWSER}        gc

*** Keywords ***
Open Login Page
    [Documentation]    Opens browser to login page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //*[@id="mbr-login-greeting"]    timeout=60s
```

As advised, please go through the [robotframework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#example-resource-file) for this.